# Move data within dataframe conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some data with two "measurement series". What I'd like to do is essentially copy and paste the values from columns C&D of Series A where type equals 0 to columns A&B of Series B where the first occurrence of the Name and Day columns are equal to those found in Series A and the values of columns A&B are not nan.

I've tried getting the length of Series A data and using it to do a shift, but that isn't robust as it assumes the data is always in the same order and seems to break if there's more than one Name in a measurement series because then the shift could be off.

How can I accomplish this in a more robust way?

Input

```
      Name    Day       Type     A     B     C     D      Meas_Series
0     Test1   20230101  0        3456  7890  0.123 0.456  Series A
1     Test1   20230101  1        6789  1234  nan   nan    Series A
2     Test1   20230101  2        8901  2345  nan   nan    Series A
3     Test1   20230102  0        2345  6789  0.345 0.678  Series A
4     Test1   20230102  1        5678  9012  nan   nan    Series A
5     Test1   20230102  2        3456  7890  nan   nan    Series A
6     Test1   20230101  99       3456  7890  nan   nan    Series B
7     Test1   20230101  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
8     Test1   20230101  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
9     Test1   20230102  99       2345  6789  nan   nan    Series B
10    Test1   20230102  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
11    Test1   20230102  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
```

Output

```
      Name    Day       Type     A     B     C     D      Meas_Series
0     Test1   20230101  0        3456  7890  0.123 0.456  Series A
1     Test1   20230101  1        6789  1234  nan   nan    Series A
2     Test1   20230101  2        8901  2345  nan   nan    Series A
3     Test1   20230102  0        2345  6789  0.345 0.678  Series A
4     Test1   20230102  1        5678  9012  nan   nan    Series A
5     Test1   20230102  2        3456  7890  nan   nan    Series A
6     Test1   20230101  99       0.123 0.456 nan   nan    Series B
7     Test1   20230101  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
8     Test1   20230101  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
9     Test1   20230102  99       0.345 0.678 nan   nan    Series B
10    Test1   20230102  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
11    Test1   20230102  99       nan   nan   nan   nan    Series B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby` to get the values that you need to "copy" and assign it to the relevant indices using boolean indexing:

```
#groupby to align values to the correct index
values = df.groupby(["Name","Day"])[["C","D"]].ffill().rename(columns={"C":"A","D":"B"})

#create mask to select rows to update
mB = df["Meas_Series"].eq("Series B")&df["A"].notnull()&df["B"].notnull()

df[["A","B"]] = df[["A","B"]].mask(mB,values)

>>> df
     Name       Day  Type         A         B      C      D Meas_Series
0   Test1  20230101     0  3456.000  7890.000  0.123  0.456    Series A
1   Test1  20230101     1  6789.000  1234.000    NaN    NaN    Series A
2   Test1  20230101     2  8901.000  2345.000    NaN    NaN    Series A
3   Test1  20230102     0  2345.000  6789.000  0.345  0.678    Series A
4   Test1  20230102     1  5678.000  9012.000    NaN    NaN    Series A
5   Test1  20230102     2  3456.000  7890.000    NaN    NaN    Series A
6   Test1  20230101    99     0.123     0.456    NaN    NaN    Series B
7   Test1  20230101    99       NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    Series B
8   Test1  20230101    99       NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    Series B
9   Test1  20230102    99     0.345     0.678    NaN    NaN    Series B
10  Test1  20230102    99       NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    Series B
11  Test1  20230102    99       NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    Series B
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be to update the Series B based on taking data subset and looping to update the original dataframe.

```
data1 = df[(df['Meas_Series'] == 'A') & (df['Type'] == 0)]

# Filter Based on series, not NAs, Day and Name
filter_B = (df['Meas_Series'] == 'B') & ~(df['A'].isna()) & ~(df['B'].isna()) & (df['Day'].isin(data1['Day']) & (df['Name'].isin(data1['Name']))) 
data2 = df[filter_B]
data2 = data2.drop_duplicates(['Name', 'Day'], keep='first') # get the first instance of Name & Day
data2 = data2.reset_index() # index will be used to match with original df
data2 = data2.merge(data1, on=['Name', 'Day'])

# loop through data2; maybe a better solution than loop exists
for idx2 in data2.index:
    # update
    idx1 = data2.loc[idx2, 'index']
    df.loc[idx1, 'A'] = data2.loc[idx2, 'C_y']
    df.loc[idx1, 'B'] = data2.loc[idx2, 'D_y']
```